# Can't create SSIS package from Import and Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server, ssis

**Problem**

I can't create a SSIS package from SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

I get to the very last screen "Run Package" and only have the option to "Run Immediately" . At the bottom of said window I get a paragraph stating:

> In SQL Server Express, Web, or Workgroup, you can run the package that the Import and Export Wizard creates, but cannot save it. To save packages that the wizard creates, you must upgrade to SQL Server Standard, Enterprise, Developer or Evaluation.

**Context**

I have several CSV files located on a client system that I want to load into a remote system hosting the SQL Server instance.

The Wizard is being run on the client system.

"Run Package " of the wizard DOES work and data loading is possible.

System permissions are such that the file system of client and host are invisible to each other. I would have `BULK INSERT`'ed otherwise.

**Technical Details**

Client System:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.50.4000.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)     6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft  MSXML                            3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
Microsoft Internet Explorer                 9.11.9600.18665
Microsoft .NET Framework                    2.0.50727.8669
Operating System                            6.1.7601
```

Host System:

```
[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2811.0 (X64)   Apr  6 2012
01:59:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition
(64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use BCP?  From the server that contains the CSV files, simply point BCP to the target server with the appropriate login credentials. Powershell is another alternative - http://www.sqlteam.com/article/fast-csv-import-in-powershell-to-sql-server

Comment: Do you install Integration Services, VS along with SSMS? you can find at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt, Product features discovered:. I'm just asking, maybe unrelated.

Comment: I'm not OP but since we have the same issue I'll respond. On our client machines we had BIDS and now we still have Data Tools installed (VS with BI templates) and we can create packages using VS and save to file. But we can do them only from 0 while prior to migration we could modificate the packages created by Wizard and saved to file

Comment: Just to let you all into the loop - I'm getting more detail from the DBA that manages this instance - I will add more detail shortly. Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

We are using SQL Server 2012 SP3 [11.0.6020.0] Enterprise Edition and SSMS 2014 [12.0.4100.1] and have the same issue.

The pictures below are:

1. SSMS version
2. Import/Export Wizard complaining about edition
3. Result of @@version showing Enterprise Edition

Since at work I had SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Enterprise Edition [10.50.2500.0] + SSMS RTM [10.50.1600.1] (they just applied SP1 on server only, all clients remained RTM) I know 100% this couple was working fine.
I patched my Studio so it then became 10.50.6000.34 and this couple: SQL Server 2008 SP3 + SSMS SP3 was still working fine.
At home I use both the server and the studio patched, i.e. both of them [10.50.6000.34] and this configuration also has no issue.

Then the Server at work migrated: all the dbs were moved onto SQL Server 2012 SP3 that is shown on the picture [11.0.6020.0], for sure **Enterprise Edition**, we are using partitioning...And here came a surprise: our clients have the new SSMS 2014 [12.0.4100.1] installed, and the Wizard does not save the packages anymore!
That was the first time I see the bizard complaining about Edition.
So I was wondered if it's a known issue or no and I googled it up. I found no workarounds or explanaitions but I did found the **Connect Item**

[Using Enterprise Edition; Can't Save SSIS Package from IMPORT WIZARD](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1402875/using-enterprise-edition-cant-save-ssis-package-from-import-wizard)

Status :

**Closed
  as Not Reproducible  Not Reproducible**

So I just concluded it's a bug that won't be fixed  (ok. because we cannot give any reproducible scenario), but it's just there

I had no chance to test your version [10.50.4000.0] and tis is the first time I read that the issue persisted on 2008 R2. I thought it was SSMS 2014's bug

[image: SSMS 2014]

[image: ERROR][image: @@VERSION]